# How to use PV Player in android?

Tags: android, video, media-player

I want to play video via PV Player, how can I do that? Or is there a class of PV Player in android?
Thanks

Comment: post your code solution so others can learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can but it will take some doing as I understand it MediaPlayer uses PVPlayer.  You can find out more by reading the [documentation](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/external/opencore/doc/mio_developers_guide.pdf)